# Rounding a double to one Decimal place not working.

Tags: java, eclipse, double, rounding, decimal-point

first of all i'd like to point out that i know this is a topic covered a lot but after about an hour of looking at other questions and trying what is suggested there i still can't get this to work.

I'm performing a binary search through Performances for numbers that are within 0.1 of a given number time. however, i need both the min/max targets and the number we are searching with (average) to be rounded to only one decimal place.
the method assumes that performance is sorted in ascending order.

```
        public static int binarySearch(Performance[] performances, double time) {


    if (performances == null){
    return -1;
    }



    int first = 0;
    int last = performances.length - 1;
    double targetMax = time + 0.1;
    double targetMin = time - 0.1;
    targetMax = Math.round((targetMax * 100)) / 100.0;
    targetMin = Math.round((targetMin * 100)) / 100.0;


    while (first <= last){
                int mid = (first + last)/2;
                double average = performances[mid].averageTime();
                average = Math.round((average * 100)) / 100.0;

                if ((targetMax > average) && (targetMin < average)  ){
                        return mid; 
            }
                else if(average < targetMin){

                    last = mid -1;

                }

                else {
                    first = mid + 1;
                }


    }

            return -1;

}
```

here's where it gets weird. the rounding i have done seems to work fine for targetMax and targetMin with 9.299999999 rounding to 9.3, however when rounding average down from 9.3333333333 it returns 9.33

i really am stumped on this one, aren't i doing the exact same thing to both variables?

new to this website so please excuse anything i've left out, just ask and ill edit it in. trying my best! :)

Answer (score 3):

You're rounding both to *two* decimal places - it's just that 9.2999999 rounded is 9.30.

Change your `100`s to `10` to round to a single decimal place in each case.